# Vectorize pandas dataframe column lookup with array of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a pandas data frame of strings as given below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(97,123,size=(3, 4), dtype=np.uint8).view('S1'), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
```

Out:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  q  g  v  f
1  l  m  u  u
2  r  r  j  w
```

I also have a list of column names.

```py
col_list = [['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

I want to slice `df` and apply an operation as follows:

```py
df[col_list[1]].values.sum(axis=1)
```

Out:

```
array(['qg', 'lm', 'rr'], dtype=object)
```

Similarly, I need to do this operation for all items in `col_list`. I can do this in a for loop, but that will be slow with a large list. Is there any way to vectorize this, so that I can pass `col_list` as a numpy array and the result is a numpy 2D array of shape `(len(col_list), len(df.index))`.

Point is, it needs to be fast for a large list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy` with `r_`, `cumsum`, and `hsplit`:

```
import numpy as np

arr_list = np.hsplit(df.loc[:, np.r_[[i for l in col_list for i in l]]].values, 
               np.cumsum(list(map(len, col_list))))
res1 = list(map(lambda x:np.sum(x, 1), arr_list))[:-1]
```

is about 60x faster than normal loop, in case `col_list` has 3000 lists:

```
col_list = [['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']] * 1000
```

`numpy`:

```
%%timeit

arr_list = np.hsplit(df.loc[:, np.r_[[i for l in col_list for i in l]]].values, 
               np.cumsum(list(map(len, col_list))))
res1 = list(map(lambda x:np.sum(x, 1), arr_list))[:-1]
# 24.3 ms ± 3.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`for` loop:

```
%%timeit

for l in col_list:
    df[l].values.sum(axis=1)
# 1.53 s ± 62.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Validation:

```
all(all(i == j) for i,j in zip(res1, res2))
# True
```